# how to get data for last calender week in redshift

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift

I have a below query that I run to extract material movements from the last 7 days.
Purpose is to get the data for the last calender week for certain reports.

```
select 
*
From
redshift
where 
posting_date between CURRENT_DATE - 7 and CURRENT_DATE - 1
```

That means I need to run the query on every Monday to get the data for the former week.
Sometimes I am too busy on Monday or its vacation/bank holiday. In that case I would need to change the query or pull the data via SAP.

Question:
Is there a function for redshift that pulls out the data for the last calender week regardless when I run the query?

I already found following solution

```
SELECT id FROM table1
WHERE YEARWEEK(date) = YEARWEEK(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

But this doesnt seem to be working for redshift sql

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift offers a [`DATE_TRUNC('week', datestamp)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html) function. Given any `datestamp` value, either a date or datetime, it gives back the date of the preceding Sunday.

So this might work for you. It filters rows from the Sunday before last, up until but not including, the last Sunday, and so gets a full week.

```sql
SELECT id
  FROM table1
 WHERE date >= DATE_TRUNC('week', NOW()) - INTERVAL '1 WEEK'
   AND date <  DATE_TRUNC('week', NOW())
```

**Pro tip:** Every minute you spend learning your DBMS's date/time functions will save you an hour in programming.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I receive the following Error:

ERROR [42601] [Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState 42601] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 9: and date >= DATE_TRUNC('week', NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK

Comment: Interval should be in quotes, i.e. '1 week'